# How can I save the current time stamp for audio progress in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a podcast app using [Just audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio).

How can I save the current timestamp, so that the playback will start from the same location the next time the app is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to events of `positionStream` method:

```
audioPlayer.positionStream.listen((event) {
      if (event.inMilliseconds != 0) {
        var duration = audioPlayer.duration!.inMilliseconds; //get the duration of audio
        progress = (event.inMilliseconds / duration)*100 // get the current position in percent
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, however this does not fully answer my question, as I want to know how to save this to somewhere where I can retrieve it in the next session

Comment: You can use a local database like object_box, moor or hive to save your data.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upvote, but I have accepted the answer. One more question: Is it possible to have the position stream inside a Provider?

Comment: I think it is possible.

Comment: The last question: The position stream seems to get the position multiple times a second. Is saving to a local database that often expensive (in terms of battery life)

Comment: You should save it when user pauses the music or exits from the screen.